# SpringBoot Integration testing Sybase and Testcontainers

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5, testcontainers

Is it possible to use a sybase database with Testcontainers to do the integration testing with spring boot?

I can not install docker on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly for your situation, you need docker to use Testcontainers.
https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/

I would recommend to use maybe an H2 database or do a test config to use another "real" database when test are executed.

Have fun!